# Save screenshots to Google Drive (Samsung S3)

Tags: automation, screenshots, google-drive

I can't figure out the easiest way to save screenshots automatically to Google Drive.

Is there a Google Drive folder and an app that makes screenshots and saves them into this folder? OR, a default folder for screenshots which be added to Google Drive?

I know I can upload the fotos to Google+, but I would like to avoid this manual step.

Thanks a lot!